# Running tests from Gem in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

Let's suppose I'm using gem *Foobar* in a Rails project. How can I run the tests of this gem?

I mean, something like

```
rake test Foobar
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Also, can I run the tests of all my dependencies?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to run the tests combined instead of separately? Why not just run Foobar whenever you modify the module?

Comment: I assume Foobar is not a gem of my own.